# RXJS Observables and Subjects good practice with redux to process data with multiple sources

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, observable, subject

Using a redux architecture and Observables, I am in a situation when I need to process data after fetching different asynchronous sources.

This is how it is supposed to work:

1. A top component ensures the data is loaded in the store in the correct format.
2. A container component subscribes to the 4 datasets and thanks to a combineLatest I process the data when each peaces are gathered,

This seems to work well, but I am not quite sure it is the right way to do.

**What is the preferred implementation in this scenario? How would you unsubscribe services and/or access to store? How do you instantiate your observables or subjects?**

I am looking here for any best practice or pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a bit more experience on the subject, the answer now seems clear: **use Effects**.

As API calls are side-effects, your effects can quietly request the data and wait with a `combineLatest` in order to combine the different datasets.

When this is done, and still in the effect, you can dispatch an action to store the data.

Then, a selector linked to the processed data will provide data to the component.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using NgRx? I assume so since that is the library that implements the redux pattern.

I often find with NgRx that I don't need to implement my own Subject/BehaviorSubject and instead build selectors.

You could build a selector that combines the desired set of data so that the component can simply get the data without having to know about the structure of the store.

Comment: Your answer is correct but since I have some side-effects, Effects are in fact the best choice for keeping the application clean.